# Push notifications from a Flask application

Tags: python, flask, websocket, push-notification

I am sure this has been covered in some other question on SO but I am unable to recognize it. My problem is simple. I have a Flask REST app where an external party can post some information to one end point (say /post_event). I then want to be able to publish this received information to refresh a browser page automatically. Assume there is a browser window open to the same Flask app home page which I want to refresh. How do I do this? I tried websockets but couldn't see how I can get it to work. What other technologies can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at AJAX: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/jquery/ You would not need a full page refresh, and the data would be fetched asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you had asynchronous techniques to refresh your clients.

The first option is WebSocket, but you should try something like `socket.io` on `Express` and write a service for your updating functionality. It's like a separate service that relays messages to your clients, but your `REST` API is on the flask.

The second option is using server-sent events; You can connect with the server, and the server sends clients all the updates. I found this module for `flask`: [flask-sse](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-sse)

There are also some frameworks like [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) that provide concurrency; Of course, you need to read more about this framework to see if it can help with your problem or not. There are some techniques like `long-polling` that you can implement with this framework.

In the end, I had the same situation in my company, and we decided not to use python for our live updating things because the `express` framework with the `socket.io` package has a lot of features that can solve anything you want in action.